# Erro java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""

Tags: java, android

Ao executar o meu app aparece o erro:

`java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""`

Já não sei o que fazer.

O erro acontece quando eu deixo um valor em branco, por exemplo, o app faz a soma de 2 números se o usuário digitar apenas um número e clicar em somar o app para e informa que ocorreu um erro, se o usuário digitar o número 1 e o número 2 e depois clicar em somar o app funciona normalmente.

Este erro começou a acontecer depois que eu usei NumberFormat para formatar o valor monetário.

Este é o código:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText valor, quantidade;
    Button btnAdicionar;
    Button btnRemover;
    Button btnNovo;

    double total2 = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        valor = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.valor);
        quantidade = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.quantidade);
        btnAdicionar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdicionar);
        btnRemover = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRemover);
        btnNovo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNovo);


        btnAdicionar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                double valorProduto = Double.parseDouble(valor.getText().toString());
                double quantidadeProduto = Double.parseDouble(quantidade.getText().toString());
                double total = valorProduto * quantidadeProduto;
                total2 = total2 + total;
                displayMensagem(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(total2));
            }
        });

        btnRemover.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                double valorProduto = Double.parseDouble(valor.getText().toString());
                double quantidadeProduto = Double.parseDouble(quantidade.getText().toString());
                double total = valorProduto * quantidadeProduto;
                total2 = total2 - total;
                displayMensagem(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(total2));

            }
        });

        btnNovo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                total2 = 0;
                displayMensagem(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(total2));
            }
        });
    }

    private void displayMensagem(String mensagem) {
        TextView valorTotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.precoTotal);
        valorTotal.setText(mensagem);
    }
}
```

Se alguém tiver uma ideia de onde eu estou errando, eu agradeço muito.

Att,
Juliâncio A Carvalho

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O seu erro é que você está tentando converter algo vazio em `double`.

**Solução:**

Verificar se o campo valor e quantidade estão vazio antes de converter. Na solução abaixo estou setando as variáveis do tipo `double` com `0` e caso os campos `valor` e `quantidade` não forem vazio, eu faço a conversão.

```
double valorProduto = 0;
double quantidadeProduto =0;

if(valor.getText().toString()!="")
   valorProduto = Double.parseDouble(valor.getText().toString());

if(quantidade.getText().toString()!="")
   quantidadeProduto = Double.parseDouble(quantidade.getText().toString());
```

**Completo:**

```
 btnAdicionar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        double valorProduto = 0;
        double quantidadeProduto =0;

        if(valor.getText().toString()!="")
           valorProduto = Double.parseDouble(valor.getText().toString());

        if(quantidade.getText().toString()!="")
           quantidadeProduto = Double.parseDouble(quantidade.getText().toString());

        double total = valorProduto * quantidadeProduto;
        total2 = total2 + total;
        displayMensagem(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(total2));
    }
});

 btnRemover.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            double valorProduto = 0;
            double quantidadeProduto =0;

            if(valor.getText().toString()!="")
               valorProduto = Double.parseDouble(valor.getText().toString());

            if(quantidade.getText().toString()!="")
               quantidadeProduto = Double.parseDouble(quantidade.getText().toString());
            double total = valorProduto * quantidadeProduto;
            total2 = total2 - total;
            displayMensagem(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(total2));

        }
    });
```